# AxisProperties Proxy Settings Stop Working in Axis 1.4

Tags: java, axis

I'm facing an issue when using Apache Axis 1.4 client to access web service through proxy.

At first things work but at some point (have not determined the interval) the proxy just stops working and I start getting: UnknownHostException

Here is the code:

```
if (proxyHost != null && !proxyHost.isEmpty()) {
        logger.warn("Using proxy server: " + proxyHost + " port " + proxyPort);
        AxisProperties.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
        AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyHost);
        AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPort", proxyPort);
        if (proxyUser != null && !proxyUser.isEmpty()) {
            logger.warn("User proxy user: " + proxyUser);
            AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyUser", proxyUser);
            AxisProperties.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", proxyPassword);
        }
    } //then make call

    Stub binding = (Stub)                       new ServiceLocator().getServiceSoap(new URL(myUrl));
```

Have I missed an important point?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It had to do with the order of the calls. My app calls multiple web services...some which require proxy and some that don't. After a server restart if a non-proxy service was called first then the AxisProperties used a default values, which do not include a proxy. If the service was called first that required a proxy then it worked fine. So I moved the AxisProperties block above UP so that it was done BEFORE any calls are made. I also set 'http.nonProxyHosts' to include services that don't need proxy.

I know this tech is getting old and it is getting harder and harder to find answers. I hope this helps someone out there who is stuck with 1.4 for the time being.